# How do I use the convolution theorem to solve an initial value problem?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform, convolution, initial-value-problems

[image: Convolution Problem]

I'm not quite sure how to use the convolution theorem for this problem. My attempt is that I took the laplace transform of both sides, however I'm confused as to what to do after. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that using Laplace Transforms, we have

$$(s^2+4s+13)X(s)=F(s)$$

Hence, solving for $X(s)$ reveals

$$\begin{align}
X(s)&=\frac{F(s)}{s^2+4s+13}\\\\
&=\frac{F(s)}{(s+2)^2+(3)^2} \\\\
&=\mathscr{L}\{f(t)\}\times \mathscr{L}\{e^{-2t}\sin(3t)u(t)\}\tag 1
\end{align}$$

Equation $(1)$ states that the Laplace Transform of $x(t)$ is equal to the product of the Laplace transform of $f(t)$ and the Laplace Transform of $h(t)=e^{-2t}\sin(3t)u(t)$.

The convolution theorem then guarantees that $x(t)=f(t)*h(t)$ and we can write

$$x(t)=\int_0^\infty f(t-u)e^{-2u}\sin(3u)\,du$$

as was to be shown!

Comment: Hi, thank you so much! I understood everything up until the u(t) part. Why do we need that?

Comment: Oh, that is just the unit step.  It comes out naturally when inverting the Laplace Transform here.

Comment: And you're welcome.  My pleasure.  -Mark